# The weird projection from SO(2n)/B to maximal isotropic grassmannian

Tags: linear-algebra, flag-varieties

Take the generalized flag variety $SO(2n,\mathbb{C})/B$, considered as the moduli of isotropic flags (according to the form $\langle e_i, e_{2n+1-j}\rangle=\delta_{ij}$)
$$F_1\subset F_2\subset\cdots F_n\subset\mathbb{C}^{2n}$$
with $\dim(F_i)=i$ and $\dim(F_n\cap\mathrm{Span}(e_1,\ldots,e_n))$ even.

Let $P$ be the maximal parabolic subgroup of $SO(2n)$ omitting one of the two nodes at the forked end.  Then $G/P$ is the moduli of isotropic subspaces of dimension $n$ in $\mathbb{C}^{2n}$.

For one of those end nodes, the description of the projection $G/B\rightarrow G/P$ is obvious; one just sends the point corresponding to the full isotropic flag to the point corresponding to the maximal subspace $F_n$.

In explicit linear algebra terms, what is the projection $G/B\rightarrow G/P$ for the maximal parabolic corresponding to the other end node on the forked end?  In other words, what is the other way to get a maximal isotropic subspace out of a full isotropic flag?

Comment: A full isotropic flag is not $F_1\subset F_2 \subset \dots \subset F_{n-1}\subset F_n \subset \mathbb{C}^{2n}$.  A full isotropic flag is $F_1\subset F_2 \subset \dots \subset F_{n-1}$ together with a pair $F_{n-1}\subset F'_n$ and $F_{n-1}\subset F''_n$ such that $F'_n$ and $F''_n$ are  distinct isotropic subspaces.

Comment: "You won't believe this 1 weird projection from..."

Comment: @JasonStarr Thanks for the hint (and, really, one should dispense with $F_{n-1}$ altogether and just think of it as the moduli with two Lagrangian subspaces which define $F_{n-1}$ as their intersection).  Followup question which I'll try to answer here in a few days if no one knows: Can this viewpoint allow us to dispense with the annoying subtle parity conditions in the linear algebra definition of type D Schubert varieties?

Comment: Followup to the above:  No it can't.  This is stated in the appendix to Buch, Kresch, and Tamvakis, _A giambelli formula for even orthogonal Grassmannians_.  An explicit example in D4 is the pair 34127856 and 46718235 (usual embedding into S8), which are incomparable in Bruhat order but comparable using dimensions of subspaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The other projection goes to the other Lagrangian subspace containing $F_{n-1}$.  If you look at $F_{n-1}^\perp/F_{n-1}$, this is a 2-dimensional space with symmetric non-degenerate bilinear form.  Thus, it has exactly 2 isotropic lines (there are coordinates where the matrix of the form is $\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1\\ 1&0\end{bmatrix}$, in which case the coordinate lines are the only isotropic ones), whose preimages are the spaces $F_n$ and $F_n'$ canonically.